# Use a subroutine to exit a `do while` loop in Fortran

Tags: loops, fortran, exit

I have a long conditional statement to determine whether to exit a `do while` loop that I use in several places.

```
if (long_class_name <= something + 0.5 .and. &
    long_class_name >= something - 0.5 .and. &
    long_class_name <= some_other_thing + 0.5 .and. &
    long_class_name >= some_other_thing - 0.5 .and. &
    yet_another_thing == -999.0) exit
```

Is there a way return an `exit` statement via a subroutine or function in Fortran, like:

```
call check_for_exit
```

It would be nice to **not** have to add variables, etc. for doing so (e.g. return a logical from a function, that I then do a simpler `if` on):

```
exit_now = check_exit()
if (exit_now == .true.) exit
```

Comment: Using a flag variable is a fairly standard pattern. It makes the code more flexible in the future, it also allows you to fiddle with the logic during debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use a logical function like in your example and directly test it (without an additional variable):

```
if ( check_exit() ) exit
```

Or, if you want to use integers, e.g. negative integers denote errors and positive ones are warnings:

```
if ( complicated_check() > 0 ) then
  print *, 'WARNING'
elseif( complicated_check() < 0 ) then
  exit
endif
```

Although this is starting to get inefficient without auxiliary variables ;-)

Comment: I feel like Shawn C is right with using flagging. Great answer. I guess I'll need to play around with this concept a bit more to understand what is best in what scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle multiple return values, assuming f90+ you can use `select case` to avoid the auxiliary variable (or calling the function twice)

```
 select case ( complicated_check() )
  case (1:)
   print*,'Warning'
  case (:-1)
   exit
 end select
```